# Why do we use the following formatting strings in python

Tags: string, formatting, python-2.7

It's only been a couple of days since I started learning Python and had a few questions.

1. Why do we use formatting strings in python such as:
   `%s` and `%d` ?
2. Can anyone tell me some more about formatting strings and what they do?

Comment: As for (1), what alternatives are you comparing it to?

Answer (score 1):

1. The `%s` formatting style comes from the tradition of C's `printf` family of functions. Python 3 introduces a [new formatting syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) that bears more resemblance to Java formatting APIs, but the printf-style formatting remains popular among programmers.
2. Check the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).